# Change the values of a list?

Tags: list, variables, loops, count, indexing

```
liste = [1,2,8,12,19,78,34,197,1,-7,-45,-97,-32,23]

liste2 = []

def repetisjon(liste,liste2):

    for count in liste:
        if count > 0:
            liste2.append(1)
        elif count < 0:
            liste2.append(0)
    return liste2

    return (liste2)

print (repetisjon(liste,liste2))
```

The point is to change all the values of the list. If it's greater than or equal to 0, it is to be replaced by the value 1. And if it's lower than 0, it  is to be replaced by 0. But I wasn't able to change the current list. The only solution I found was to make a new list. But is there anyway to CHANGE the current list without making a new one? I tried this as well, but didnt work at all:

```
liste = [4,8,43,4,78,24,8,45,-78,-6,-7,-3,8,-12,4,36]
def repe (liste):
   for count in liste:
       if count > 0:
           count == 1
       else:
           count == 0
   print (liste)

repe(liste)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, I replace the content of liste with the transformed data. since sameliste points to the same list, its value changes too.

```
>>> sameliste = liste = [1,2,8,12,19,78,34,197,1,-7,-45,-97,-32,23]
>>> sameliste
[1, 2, 8, 12, 19, 78, 34, 197, 1, -7, -45, -97, -32, 23]
>>> liste
[1, 2, 8, 12, 19, 78, 34, 197, 1, -7, -45, -97, -32, 23]
>>> liste[:] = [int(x >= 0) for x in liste]
>>> liste
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
>>> sameliste
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
>>>
```